# Double "1/3" as ConverterParameter

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, converters

I have to convrt a double to other using a converter and a parameter:

This is my XAML stub:

```
Converter={StaticResource ToOtherDoubleConverter}, ConverterParameter=-1/2
```

this is the converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class DoubleToOtherDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value * double.Parse(parameter.ToString());
    }
```

Now, this is useless to say that this is culture dependent, etc..

Is there a way to "hardcode" a double to be recognized as double? 
Because the above variant could be written in different ways, by eg.:

```
ConverterParameter=-1/2
ConverterParameter=-0.5
ConverterParameter=-0,5
etc.
```

or also

```
double.Parse(parameter.ToString());
(double)parameter;
```

etc...

One more question:

How can I specify **`1/3`** in the floating format? something like

```
ConverterParameter=0.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

Comment: Are you sure it's being passed in as a numeric value at all?  In my experience most XAML values end up passed in as strings, even if they look like numbers...

Comment: @Dan Puzey: as `object` in general... as strings perhaps finally, this is why I am asking, because don't know :)

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the first line of your converter you can check `value.GetType()` and see what it's being passed in as...

Comment: @Dan: have reason: `parameter.GetType() {Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public class DoubleToOtherDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var frac = ((string) parameter).Split('/');
        if (frac.Length == 2)
            return (double) value*double.Parse
                (frac[0])/double.Parse(frac[1]);
        return (double) value* double.Parse(((string) parameter)
            .Replace(",", "."));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: :) finally, this was the "hard" variant that I don't like. But as it the only that works for me, I have no choice. Just I added CultureInfo.InvariantCulture at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunetly not, the IValueConverter interface provides methods accepting object - which is not type save - instead of generics.
But you could add a Culture.InvariantCulture to your parse and throw an exception. This way you would notify the user about the "incorrect" format.

Comment: you cant. 1/3 is not a nummber, its an arithmetic expression. For your purpose I'd create two converters -> MultiplierConverter and DividerConverter. You could also just invert the logic and just create a Divider converter, but this would make your xaml barley readable...